# Comma to specify a port number in sqlalchemy using mssql+pyodbc

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am connecting to MSSQL Server instance using a SSH tunnel with my localhost at a port number which is not the default 1433. In order to connect to the instance, I have to specify the server name with port number separated by a comma, for example, localhost,1267.

I am able to successfully connect it from SQL Server Management Studio and Azure Data Studio but the connection string does not work when I specify the port number with a comma in mssql+pyodbc connection string server name in my python project.

My connection string looks like below -

```
mssql+pyodbc://user:password@localhost,1267/instance?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server
```

I have tried specifying the port number as localhost:1267 but get following error -

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Successful connection from data studio -

[image]

Comment: `…@localhost:1267/…` is the correct format for a SQLAlchemy connection URI

Comment: Yes saw that in the docs, I have tried and it did not work

Comment: Please [edit] your question to better describe what you mean by "did not work". For example, do you receive an error message? If so, what is it?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have updated my question and added the exception message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using IP address in the connection string instead of localhost resolved the issue. The updated connection string looks like below  -

```
mssql+pyodbc://user:password@127.0.0.1,1267/instance?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server
```